# Delete line starting with a word in Javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have few lines on text.

> Random 14637547548546546546sadas3463427
>   Random 1463754754854654654sadsa63463427
>   Macroflex 1463754754854654sada65463463427
>   Random 146375475485465465sdas463463427
>   Random 1463754754854654fdasf65463463427

I would like to find a line what starts with **Macroflex** (in this case) and replace/delete it. This is what I have so far... I have tried over and over with regex, but it makes my head hurt. Can anyone give me an advice?

```
var myRegex = data.replace('Macroflex', '')
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to replace to the end of the line:

```
var myRegex = data.replace(/^Macroflex.*$/gm, '');
```

Note that you have to specify the `m` flag to let `^` and `$` work with newlines.

If you want to remove the newline after the line, you can match it:

```
var myRegex = data.replace(/^Macroflex.*\n?/gm, '');
```

This works since `.` does not match newlines.

The `/g` flag enables removing multiple occurrences of the line.

Comment: and use /gm instead of /m if you have multiple occurrences of the line

Comment: Sweet, now my comments work in MathJax: https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/equations-and-matrices

Comment: How about ignoring spaces which the line might be indented with?

Comment: I noticed that if the last line is removed, an empty line is left in there

Comment: If you're using Window like me, replace `\n` in the regex string with `\r\n`.